# WooCommerce Output a text when chosen product variation is in stock

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I've been rattling my head on how to add specific text through the variation.php template if a product variation's **stock quantity** is greater than zero.

The text is "Usually ships within 2-3 business days".

We take backorders, so if the stock is zero it can't display the text.

I'm able to display the text when each variation is selected with a function in the functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation','load_variation_settings_fields' );
function load_variation_settings_fields( $variations ) {

    $variations['text_field'] = 'Usually ships within 2-3 business days'; 

    return $variations;
}
```

And adding this code to the variation.php template file:

```
<div class="woocommerce-variation-custom-text-field">
{{{ data.variation.text_field }}}
</div>
```

I'm having trouble grabbing the stock quantity of the variation selected and if it is greater than zero display the text *edit*- "Usually ships within 2-3 business days"*edit*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom function has 3 arguments that are enabled by the hook:

- The the variation data array: **`$variation_data`** *(that is returned)*
- The **`WC_Product_Variable object`**: **`$product`**
- The **`WC_Product_Variation object`**: **`$variation`**

So you can use the third argument to get the quantity for the current variation this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'load_variation_settings_fields', 10, 3 );
function load_variation_settings_fields( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) {

    // Display shipping delay text when stock quantity exist
    if( $variation->get_stock_quantity() > 0 )
        $variation_data['text_field'] = __('Usually ships within 2-3 business days'); 
    else $variation_data['text_field'] = __(''); // You can add a text if needed

    return $variation_data;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested in WooCommerce version 3+ and works

Comment: So weird - Source code shows the text outputting to the browser but it's not displaying. Solution works on my dev server(http) but not on the live server(https).

Comment: @Shinosky how can I help you then? … what is the difference between your test server and the live one?

Comment: Nevermind forgot to add the {{{ data.variation.text_field }}} line of code to the template file on the live site lol. Thanks for the help LoicTheAztec!